# So, I am using Kotlin and I need to create an array of teams and then an incrementor to print out the number of teams in the array

Tags: arrays, kotlin, increment

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

val teams = listof("Browns", "Rams", "Eagles", "Steelers", "Redskins", "Lions", "Packers", "Bears", "Cardinals", 
"Giants")

for (name in teams) {
    print(name)
}

    
}
```

This is what I have so far but then I get this error. I have been trying to solve this for a few hours now and can't seem to figure it out. Help is much appreciated.

```
Unresolved reference: listof
Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun print(message: Any?): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Boolean): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Byte): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Char): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: CharArray): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Double): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Float): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Int): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Long): Unit defined in kotlin.io
public inline fun print(message: Short): Unit defined in kotlin.io
```

Answer (score 2):

The first error message is `Unresolved reference: listof`, this means that the `listof` you wrote doesn't correspond to any known symbol.

In fact, in your case this is because you have a typo in the name: you need a capital O in `listOf` (see [the doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html)). In general in Kotlin, names that are composed of multiple words are written in camelCase. Lower camelCase for function names and properties, upper CamelCase (or Pascal case) for types/classes. You can read more about conventions in the [Coding conventions page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html) from the docs.

The other error is an `Overload resolution ambiguity`. This means Kotlin doesn't know which `print` function you're talking about here (it gives you the list of all the `print` functions it knows about). This is actually due to the first error, because the compiler doesn't know the type of `val teams` because it doesn't know what the unknown `listof` returns. Once you fix the typo, this second error will go away too.

Comment: Yes, that worked out perfectly. one more question how would I use an increment and print out the number of teams in the array

Comment: @Lynn what do you mean by an "increment"? Do you mean a loop that increments a counter? You don't need that. You can just `println(teams.size)` directly.

Comment: How would I use a for loop to increment a counter

Comment: You likely almost never need it in Kotlin. There are functional extensions on collections that allow to achieve most aggregations in a simpler way than a for loop. But if you really want to use a `for` loop for learning purposes, have a look at the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#for-loops). You can define a `var` outside the loop and update it inside.